# What size category is a wereraven in hybrid form?

Tags: dnd-5e, creature-size, lycanthropy

Lycanthropes in general can shift between their humanoid, animal, and hybrid forms. In humanoid form they are Medium size and in animal form they are whatever size the animal normally is, but there is no clear indication on what size the hybrid form is.

A wereraven would be Tiny in animal form, since [ravens](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/raven) are Tiny. Would the hybrid form be Medium (like the humanoid form), Small (halfway between the two), or Tiny (like the raven form)?

The [wereraven](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/wereraven)'s statblock is in

> *Curse of Strahd*, p. 242

and it lists the Shapechanger trait:

> ***Shapechanger.*** The wereraven can use its action to polymorph into a raven-humanoid hybrid or into a raven, or back into its human form. Its statistics, other than its size, are the same in each form.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Because it does not specify, Medium.

In the ***shapechanger*** ability for a werebear (MM 208):

> The werebear can use its action to polymorph into a Large bear-humanoid hybrid or into a Large bear, or back into its true form, which is humanoid.

Because wereravens don't specify in their stat block, it would appear as though they stay the same size.

This is muddied a little by WotC describing "Large bear" and not "tiny raven", but I assume that is because there are more than 1 size of bear (black and brown bears are Medium and Large, respectively), but only 1 size of raven.

Comment: I think that's correct on why the Large Bear gets specified while the others don't.  All the other hybrid forms don't specify a size, so presumably they are the same size as their humanoid forms, just with animal traits added on.